# Update mysql database and files based on "master one"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I want to build a application that have a "master database" (MySQL) and some "slaves", so when something is changed or added on the master, the slaves will be changed too. Is this possible?

This idea is possible for files? (when the file is modified on the master, all slaves will download them and overwrite the old ones)

All of them will be wordpress installations, the master one will be stored on a internet server, and the slaves will be local (apache server) with internet access.

Comment: Anything is possible - http://superuser.com/questions/90301/sync-two-mysql-databases